# Collections of homebrew installs

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

Is there a way to group together homebrew installs?

Let's say I want to install a collection of stuff - homebrew/versions/mysql51, homebrew/versions/ruby192, rvm.

But I also want to be able to switch to another collection - mysql, ruby, rbenv. And when I switch the others are turned off, so as not to conflict.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I exactly follow, but you can script the unlink/link.

```
$ ./coll1
$ ./coll2
```

where coll1 and coll2 are scripts, bash functions or aliases

```
coll1() {
    brew unlink mysql51
    brew unlink ruby192
}
coll2() {
    brew link mysql
    brew link ruby
}
```